# union tables with different schema in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What is the best way to append table with different Schema?

**Table 0 Schema**

[image: Table0 Schema]

[image: Table0 Preview]

**Table 1 Schema**

[image: Table1 Schema]

[image: Table1 Preview]

---

this works fine

```
SELECT img1, NULL as img2 FROM `xxx.staging.table0` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT img1, img2 FROM `xxx.staging.table1`
```

but is there a way to append tables without having to explicitly declare each column?

and also is it good practice to save table 0 as

```
SELECT img1, CAST(NULL as string) as img2 FROM `modemutti-8d8a6.staging.table0`
```

making sure img2 is a string:

[image]

and then afterwards appending the 2 tables with the exact same schema?

```
SELECT * FROM `xxx.staging.table1ab` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `xxx.staging.table1`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table0`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT '', '') ON FALSE
```

**Note**: in `(SELECT '', '')` you need to have as many `''` as number of extra fields you have in table1 - so total number of fields in both tables are the same

You can test, play with above using dummy data as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table0` AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' img1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xxx' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'yyy' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zzz' 
),  `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 'bbb' img1, 'ccc' img2, 'ddd' img3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg'
)
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table1`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.table0`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT '', '') ON FALSE
```

with result

```
Row     img1    img2    img3     
1       bbb     ccc     ddd  
2       eee     fff     ggg  
3       aaa     null    null     
4       xxx     null    null     
5       yyy     null    null     
6       zzz     null    null
```

Comment: can the `SELECT * FROM project.dataset.table0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT '', '') ON FALSE` can also be replaced with just `SELECT *, null, null FROM project.dataset.table0`? How is that too different?

Comment: Do you know if this approach can be made to work with columns that are record-type?